# Text won't align left on Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

How do you make text align in a div on Tailwind: I have tried...

1. items-start
2. text-left
3. float-left

on both the child and the parent component but the text will not budge and stays stuck in the middle.

The logo with "Web For Professionals" stays stuck in the middle of the div and will not align to the left whatever I try, does anyone know how to force it to align to the left?

```
 <nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5 rounded dark:bg-gray-900 sticky top-0 z-50 text-left items-start">
  <div class="container flex flex-wrap justify-between items-start text-left">
    <a href="https://webforprofessionals.com/" className="flex items-start text-left">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/webforprofessionals.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/cropped-facebooklogo.jpg?resize=202%2C99&ssl=1" class="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9" alt="Web For Professionals Logo" />
        <span class="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Web For Professionals</span>
    </a>
    <button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="navbar-default" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
      <svg class="w-6 h-6" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto" id="navbar-default">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: [Aligned for me](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MKEFWZWh0q)? Unless this isn't what you want? I don't know what you mean then.

Answer (score 1):

Remove container from the first div class.

For some reason, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this class name to your div:

> left-0

to manipulate the placement of your element.

You can understand more about it [in this link of docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apply this option to your code, so I ended up solving my problem:

**Example**

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-fixed"> 
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-left"> <!-- try to respect the class name -->
        <th class="col-xs-3">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### Dynamic class names

*The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.*

*If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:*

**Don't construct class names dynamically**

```
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Let me know if you manage to solve the problem...!